# How to match a struct

Tags: scheme, racket

I want to match a struct `test`, and build a struct from that, but how can I do that?
I can't even use `eval` to do this?

Please reference to the code,

```
#lang racket

  (struct test (num) #:prefab)

  (define s `((AK= #(struct:test 100))
   (AV)
   ))

  (define ns (make-base-namespace))
   (define (set-state-space-vals!)
   (namespace-set-variable-value! 'test test #f ns)
   )

(match s
   [`((AK= #(struct:test ,val) (AV)))  ;; can't match
     (displayln val)
    ]
   [`((AK= ,val) (AV))   ;; can match, but how to build the struct?
     (struct? (eval val ns))
     (match-define (struct test (num)) (eval val ns)) ;this will fail
     (displayln num)
    ]  )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you were looking for something like this:

```
(struct test (num) #:prefab)

(define s '((AK= #s(test 100)) (AV)))

(match s
  [`((AK= ,(struct test (val))) (AV))
   (displayln val)])
```

Also, in general using `eval` in a situation like this is highly inadvisable. When in doubt, do not use `eval`. See [this blog post](http://blog.racket-lang.org/2011/10/on-eval-in-dynamic-languages-generally.html) for a longer explanation. You might also want to see the Guide entries on [prefabs](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/define-struct.html?q=prefab#(tech._prefab)) and [pattern matching](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/match.html).

Comment: We should add that #(struct:test 100) is actually a vector literal containing 'struct:test and 100.

Comment: @Asumu If I can use `eval` to get the struct instance directly, it would suit my need perfect~~

Answer (score 1):

Also, though it's not in the documentation for match, `((AK= #s(test ,val)) (AV)) is a valid pattern.